# Xcode 7.1 certificate issue and invalid profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

We are two devs working on the same ios project, using same developer id. When one of us runs app on device, xcode offers to fix a certificate issue. After agree, xcode kills all existing certificates and invalidates provisioning profiles. This kills each other provisioning profiles.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Create developer certificate and provisioning profile.
2. Share it with other developer.
3. Create new profile by xcode when it says "there is no profile to run on device" (and gets "Fix issue" button).

Expected Results:
Previously created provisioning profiles and developer certificates should remain valid.

Actual Results:
It invalidates existing developer certificates and provisioning profiles.

Version:
xcode 7.1

How we can fix this issue?

Comment: Every time I have ever tried to let Xcode "fix" a provisioning issue it jacks everything up. I would suggest just doing everything through the developer portal, and not letting Xcode attempt it's fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Never use the "Fix issue" button is one of the best tips given by this article : http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/116436789850/follow-these-guidelines-and-never-struggle-with).

Instead learn how to manage provisioning profiles:

1/ Connect to your member center from http://developer.apple.com

2/ Generate a developer certificate, you will have to share the private key with your other developer to use the same account (or you could invite him if you had an entreprise account)

3/ Register your device UDIDs

4/ Generate a development provisioning profile

5/ Configure your project to use this provisioning profile and developer certificate

6/ Build and run on your devices (and never struggle again with provisioning with provisioning profiles!)

Here is all the documentation you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Hope that helps.

Cyril